# PayPal checkout for existing user not working

Tags: paypal, magento2.1.5

**Magento-2.1.5** With **php 5.6**

**issue:**

`PayPal checkout` for existing user not working. When you say continue to PayPal keeps spinning forever. In console, I got this error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found):rest/default/v1/carts/mine/selected-payment-method

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 /resources/checkout/#payment:1
at JSON.parse ()
at Object.process (error-processor.js:19)
at Object. (set-payment-method.js:50)
at fire (jquery.js:3099)
at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:3211)
at done (jquery.js:9312)
at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:9720)
```

help should be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run these commands in your root installation path.

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf vendor/* var/view_preprocessed/*/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
composer install ; composer update -vvv;
php -r "opcache_reset();"
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Comment: I don't think mage work in magento2. What you are suggesting is clean the static files and var files flush cache and reindex and upgrade...right?

Comment: no, it's to mainly update your components installed, so it'll do the deploy and clear the cache.